# Is memcached a distributed hash table?

Tags: memcached

Since memcached can store data for a key, does that make it a dht? The documentation calls it a distributed memory object caching system which sounds similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DHT is an application that can be built using Memcached as the backing store. For an example see - https://github.com/nisere/dht